# apt-get purge mariadb leaving traces which stop mysql install

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, mariadb

I'm trying to bug test a database issue with a website I'm working on. I would like to see if switching between mariadb and MySQL fixes the issue (however unlikely that is). I thought this would be a simple processes on a dev machine (I don't have any data to worry about / back up).

I used the command

```
sudo apt-get purge mariadb*
```

and then I entered

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

And was surprised to receive this lovely error.

```
   invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libmariadbclient18 (5.5.32+maria-1~precise) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried dkpg --configure -a and was greeted with this

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
```

I noticed that there wasa  line which said

```
setting up libmariadbclient18
```

which makes no sense to me since I purged mariadb* earlier. Anyone out there have an idea of what's going on?

**Update**
I went right to the heart of the issue and did

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.5
```

and was greeted with

```
Note, selecting 'mariadb-client-5.5' instead of 'mysql-client-5.1'
```

Not sure what's going on.

**update2**

```
sudo apt-get purge libmariadbclient-dev
```

has me installing the correct client, still getting an error on install.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to remove the `libmariadbclient18` package. Remove that first.

Comment: I did apt-get purge libmariadbclient18. went to install and saw this message. 
`The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libmariadbclient18 libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5`

So it's not because I haven't uninstalled it. for some reason apt-get is installing mariadb's client.

Comment: So I found the reason why my client was installing mariadb's client. `sudo apt-get purge libmariadbclient-dev` made it so mysql-server installs the correct client. 

It does not, however, fix my error.

Answer (score 0):

If you can uninstall mysql-server and just delete ALL DATABASES, you can try this (again, be sure you have a working backup of all your databases):

rm -rf /var/lib/mysql

and then reinstall mysql-server.